# Custom Commands for Skype for Business Client

Tags: .net, skype-for-business, lync-client-sdk, lync-server-2010

Am trying to add custom commands to Skype for Business Client menu but whether this option is available for "**Skype for Business Client**". As per i know this is available for **Lync Client**. Any documentation is present for adding custom commands to Skype for Business Client menu??

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by adding some registry entries. The [Lync 2013](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg412788(v=ocs.15).aspx) method still works.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Lync\SessionManager\Apps\{1F9F07C6-7E0B-462B-AAD7-98C6DBEA8F69}]
"Name"="Contoso Sales Contact Manager"
"HelpMessage"="The Contoso Sales Contact Manager is not installed. Contact the Help Desk for more information."
"ApplicationType"=dword:00000000
"ApplicationInstallPath"="C:\\cscm.exe"
"Path"="C:\\cscm.exe %user-id% %contact-id%"
"SessionType"=dword:00000001
"ExtensibleMenu"="ConversationWindowActions;MainWindowRightClick"
```

Comment: Note: For Skype for Business 2016, I had to use `16.0` instead of `15.0`